# Even Digit Series (2,4,6,8,20,....)

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I have a series of numbers whose Nth term is a number whose all of the digits are even. The series is of course divergent , but i am interested in finding a formula to find the Nth term of this series.The beginning terms of the series is as follows:-
2,4,6,8,20,22,24,26,28,40,....

We can see that each of the numbers in the above series consists of digits that are all even numbers.
Can anyone please help me in finding the Nth term of this series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all numbers that only contain even digits.

For a general formula look at this link https://oeis.org/A014263

Comment: i was unable to find the general formula for the series from your provided link.i am very new to all this and it would be of great help if you could post the general formula somewhere in your answer it would be of huge help

Comment: Look for "From Hieronymus Fischer, Jun 06 2012: (Start)" under formula.